# Rails and AJAX Posting a Comment

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a simple blog app that reviews video games. Users can post comments on reviews.

My problem is that when I try to post a comment using AJAX(I'm a student trying to teach myself) on a review page, the page does a full refresh. The data is still submitted correctly, but then I have to reload the page in order to show the comments.

**review.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#new_comment').on('submit', function(e) {
     url = this.action

     data = {
      'authenticity_token': $("input[name='authenticity_token']").val(),
      'comment': {
        'content': $("#comment_content").val(),
      'user_id': $("#comment_user_id").val()
      }
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: function(response) {
        $('#comments-section ol').append(response);
      }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

**comments_controller.rb #create action**

```
  def create
    @review = Review.find_by(params[:id])
    @comment = @review.comments.new(comment_params)

    if !current_user
      redirect_to review_oath(@review), alert: "You must be logged in to add a comment"
    else
      @comment.save
      redirect_to @review
    end
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :user_id)
  end
```

**review.show.html.erb**

```
        <div id="comments-section">
          <% if @review.comments.any? %>

            <p>
              <div><br>
                <br>
              <ul>
                <% @review.comments.all.each do |c| %>
                  <h4 class="media-heading"><%= c.user.email %> said</h4> <br><li><p><%= c.content %></p></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </p>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The full repo is here, make sure you're on the AJAX/JQUERY branch: https://github.com/jchu4483/Rails-Assessment-/tree/ajax/jquery

Thanks, and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? Sending an ajax request will not magically cause the comment to pop up in the document. Also you should run your code through a linter such as JS-Lint or use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) as you are inadvertantly assigning two global variables (you forgot the `var` keyword).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Why exactly does the AJAX request not post to the backend? Is something in my code/logic incorrect?

Comment: Just posting an ajax request does not change the current document. It creates an entry in the database. But you either need to reload the page or modify the document for the user to see any changes.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in order to ensure the app security, I suggest you to move the authentication method to a before_action in ApplicationController and skip it for the public actions.

If you are using [devise gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/devise) you can add:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

Using this your app is secure by default.

For the comment update I recommend you to follow this approach:

Make your comment creation form an AJAX form adding the remote param and move it to a partial:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for comment, remote: true do |form|%>
  <%=form.hidden_field :review_id, review_id%>
  <%=form.text_field :content%>
  <%=form.submit :save%>
<% end %>
```

Create comments list partial too:

**_comments.html.erb**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% comments.each do |comment| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%= image_tag comment.user.avatar.url %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= comment.content %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So your review page should be something like this:

**reviews/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="review-photo">
  <%= @review.photo %>
</div>
<div class="review-content">
  <%= @review.content %>
</div>
<section class="comments">
  <div class="new-comment-container">
    <%= render 'my_new_comment_form_path', comment: Comment.new, review_id: @review.id %>
  </div>
  <div class="comments-container">
    <%= render 'my_comments_partial_path', comments: @review.comments %>
  </div>
</section>
```

Update your comments controller in order to response to AJAX on the create action:

```
   def create
    format.js do
      @review = Review.find_by(params[:review_id])
      @review.comments << Comment.create(comment_params)
    end
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params
      .require(:comment)
      .permit(:content)
      .merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
```

This code has a little refactor to ensure the commenter is the current user.

Then you should create a create.js.erb file to response to the create action, in this file you should replace the old list and the old form with the new ones:

**comments/create.js.erb**

```
$('.new-comment-container').html("<%= j render 'my_new_comment_form_path', comment: Comment.new, review_id: @review.id%>")
$('.comments-container').html("<%= j render 'my_comments_partial_path', comments: @review.comments%>")
```

I think this is a clean way to work with AJAX forms in rails.

Comment: Hello Pablo, thanks for responding! Yes, could you change the view templates to erb instead of haml?

Comment: I changed the templates to erb